# Windows Phone 8.1 ListView.ReorderMode not notifying ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1

In a Windows Phone 8.1 application (targeting Runtime not Silverlight), I have an ObservableCollection bound to a ListView, defined like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems, Mode=TwoWay}" CanReorderItems="True" ReorderMode="Enabled">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        ...etc...
```

In the ViewModel's constructor, I also have

```
ListItems.CollectionChanged += ListItems_CollectionChanged;
```

which is raising the event whenever any items are added and deleted - however, that's all handled from the VM not the View. Unfortunately, the event is not being raised when the items are reorder. I've set this up, moved some items, added a breakpoint in the event handler and added an item, and I can see the underlying ObservableCollection's order has changed as controlled from the View. So why isn't the event raising? And if it won't, what's the best practice for persisting a ListView's order in the database?

**UPDATE:**

The problem's actually bigger than I thought... it seems that the ListView.CollectionChanged event is not firing when adding an item either! It does when the application starts and loads them from the database but not when added by a user from the UI. This is very strange because the addition of items is performed using the exact same method. From the database:

```
private ViewModel MapFromModel(Item model, SQLiteAsyncConnection connection)
    {
        var viewModel = new ViewModel
        {
            Id = model.Id,
            Text = model.Text,
            Description = model.Description,
            Added = model.Added,
            Completed = model.Completed,
            DueOn = model.DueOn,
            ParentId = model.ParentId,
            DisplayOrderNumber = model.DisplayOrderNumber,
            IsNew = false
        };

        foreach (
            var childViewModel in
                connection.Table<Item>()
                    .Where(ci => ci.ParentId == viewModel.Id)
                    .ToListAsync()
                    .Result.Select(childItem => MapFromModel(childItem, connection)))
        {
            if (!_cache.Contains(childViewModel))
                _cache.Add(childViewModel);
            viewModel.AddItem(childViewModel);
        }
        return viewModel;
    }
```

You see this recursive method calls the ViewModel's AddItem() method to add children (which are of the same type). I also have an ICommand bound to a button to add other items:

```
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var viewModel = parameter as ViewModel;
        if (viewModel == null) return;

        AddItem(viewModel);
    }
public static void AddItem(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // The DisplayOrderNumber of the new item needs to be the max of the current collection + 1.
        var displayOrderNumber = viewModel.ListItems.Any()
            ? viewModel.ListItems.Max(ci => ci.DisplayOrderNumber) + 1
            : 0;
        var newText = string.Format("{0} {1}",
            viewModel.Id == Guid.Empty ? "List" : "Item", displayOrderNumber + 1);
        var newItem = new ViewModel
        {
            Text = newText,
            NewText = newText,
            ParentId = viewModel.Id,
            InEditMode = true,
            Added = DateTime.Now,
            DisplayOrderNumber = displayOrderNumber,
            IsNew = true
        };
        viewModel.AddItem(newItem);
        viewModel.Save();
    }
```

So why should the AddItem() method raise the event when called from the Service Layer but not from the ViewModel layer itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, as usual, the fault was entirely mine.

This was occurring because the event handling method ListItems_CollectionChanged was being disconnected. The cause of this was because of a Sort method that was replacing the underlying connection. I've got around this problem by adding the event handler, if needed, in the setter for the property (and of course removing any unused event handlers).